# Where JIT-ed methods of a struct are stored?

Tags: .net, memory, struct

Suppose we have a struct:

```
public struct MyStruct {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void IncrementX() {
        x++;
    }

    public void IncrementY() {
        y++;
    }
}
```

I know, that struct is a value type and a variable of a struct are represented as a copy of its data members.

I also found out, that if a struct variable is declared inside a method, its value are stored on stack (or can be stored in registers).

But, what happens when we call IncrementX() ? Where JIT compiler stores compiled code in memory and how it finds compiled code next time when the method is called again?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that A) JITed and non-JITed methods are stored in different locations and B) that struct methods and class methods are stored in different locations?  In other words, why is this question limited specifically to JITed struct methods?

Comment: In case of classes, when an object is created, GC creates data structures for an INSTANCE and for its TYPE. Method addresses are stored with TYPE data structure and INSTANCE has Type Object Pointer, which points to the TYPE object. So, in case of reference types, its clear to me, because everything goes to heap and are linked together.

But in case of value types, when a value type variable declared inside a method, stored on stack and popped after the method returns, its not so obvious.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking.  So you want to know not where the executable code of a `struct`'s method is stored, but where a `struct`'s field is stored?  Or where a local `struct` variable is stored...during or after method execution (in which case, whether that method happens to be defined on a `struct` or a `class` is inconsequential?)?  It's confusing because you have `struct` fields that are accessed within methods, all within a `struct` type, so I'm not clear which `struct` is the one you find pertinent to your question.